# AngularJs ng-repeat not working with more than one item in ng-init

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJs and working through an example which is not working correctly using ng-init and ng-repeat. This is part of my code from the body

```
<div ng-app="" ng-init="books=[
    {title:'Pride and Prejudice', author:'Jane Austen', genre:'Romance'}
    {title:'Dracula', author:'Bram Stoker', genre:'Horror'}
    {title:'The Hobbit', author:'J.R.R. Tolkien', genre:'Fantasy'}
    ]">

    <p>Here are your books:</p>
    <ol>
        <li ng-repeat="book in books">
            {{ 'Title: ' + book.title + ', Author: ' + book.author + ', Genre: ' + book.genre }}
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

If I remove the lines for Dracula and The Hobbit, the data does display but with all three books no data is displayed.

Comment: I would *strongly* advise against using the source of this example for future angular learning;  Not only are they teaching you to use `ng-init` [for the wrong purpose](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit#!), they are also using a deprecated syntax for `ng-app`;  You haven't been able to use a blank `ng-app` since angular 1.2.  Don't learn bad habits from "examples" that don't follow the current documented standard for the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the commas to separate your array items.

```
<div ng-app="" ng-init="books=[
    {title:'Pride and Prejudice', author:'Jane Austen', genre:'Romance'},
    {title:'Dracula', author:'Bram Stoker', genre:'Horror'},
    {title:'The Hobbit', author:'J.R.R. Tolkien', genre:'Fantasy'}
    ]">

    <p>Here are your books:</p>
    <ol>
        <li ng-repeat="book in books">
            {{ 'Title: ' + book.title + ', Author: ' + book.author + ', Genre: ' + book.genre }}
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

[Array syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

> [element0, element1, ..., elementN]